# IDE does not have correct classpath

Tags: java, ide, bluej

I'm using BlueJ for java, and despite having loaded in my external .jar files and the program compiling fine, It does not run with a "Failed to initialize *library*".

When I compile it into a .jar file itself however (and have the library .jars I need in the same folder) It runs fine.

How do I change the classpath of my BlueJ IDE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've switched to NetBeans, it worked right away. It seems BlueJ will not set your classpath explicitly, and the means to do so manually, if they exist, are obfuscated. BlueJ lacked a general run button as well as this capability, which in my mind makes it ill suited to program with.